# DataGridView with a row with 2 text lines

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, rows

I have one of my `DataGridView` columns that have a long text: it's possible subdivide the text in 2 or more lines and increase the height of the row?

I wish something automatic, if the text is over some size, it's splited in 2 lines.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
columnName.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

Comment: thanks @rob, now the text is wrapped, but the rows are too much thin...
http://i.stack.imgur.com/D9enc.png

Comment: ok! found it! `DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;` thanks to let me on the right way! ;)